# react-native-mapbox-gl / maps how to change styles?

Tags: react-native, dictionary, styling, react-native-mapbox-gl

I see there layers in documentation. https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps#layers
But I can't understand how I can change color of buildings and roads. And how to change text in labels. And fontsize. Please help. My task is to do contrast white-black map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can design your map at https://studio.mapbox.com/. When you publish a map, you will get a style url

Then you can add to style url to your map like this:

```
<MapboxGL.MapView
  styleURL="mapbox://styles/tijsmartens/ckjr7xuda2j0k19pjmx8hczud"
/>
```

Comment: Yes, then I found it and did exactly as you told) Thanks!

Comment: I get a blank map when I use this with any url or even `StyleURL.Light` from the API

Comment: @conor909 can you try with the exact url I used?

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the above answer, you can use mapbox's default styles likeso `styleURL={Mapbox.StyleURL.Dark}`